# Where do I put resource entity file in ~tomcat/ directory?

Tags: xml, apache, tomcat

I came across this article https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Password
where they mention use of resource entity to hide password.

I did as they suggested i.e. put

```
<!DOCTYPE Server [
 <!ENTITY % resources SYSTEM "resources.txt">
 %resources;
]>
```

in server.xml and in  mentioned

password="&resource;"

whereas in resources.txt i mention just the password value say foo123.
Then I placed resources.txt in ~tomcat/conf directory same as where server.xml is placed.

In catalina.out I am getting error like below

```
Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: The markup declarations contained or 
pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
```

This setup is not working. And I don't know how to debug this issue.
Can you please suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how this solution worked:

resources.txt is put in the same folder as server.xml i.e. ~tomcat/conf/

In resources.txt you need to write information as an entity

```
<!ENTITY resources "foo1223">
```

resources tag here should match with what you have provided in server.xml